# How to rewrite URL and add slug 'blog' in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to add in WordPress a slug (blog) only if the entry has a link date

```
https://example.com/2016-02-05-nowe-zycie-po-przeszczepie/
```

to

```
https://example.com/blog/2016-02-05-nowe-zycie-po-przeszczepie/
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please do share your htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing WordPress directives:

```
# Prefix "/blog" to URL if date at start of URL-path
RewriteRule ^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d- /blog%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed this works as intended. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.